# Proof for using the formula of cross product for area and volume of a shape

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

For two vectors $2i + 3j - 4k$ and $i + 2k$. The way I understood crops product is that we can find these two vectors magnitude. Let us say (Assumption ) $= 10$ and $7$. Now , to find area . We do $\frac 12 \times 10 \times  7 \times \sin \theta$. Probably because $10$ and $7$ are parallel to each other. And if we draw something that is not parallel to $10$ units. Then , we can find an area.
This is one way.

Second way is that we write it in discriminant form.[image]

Now , my confusion is that solving it in discriminant form , It gives area. Now , how did we take care of sin theta here and why do we write it in discriminant form.

[image]

Just a picture of how I view these Values.

Comment: Have a look if the answer below works, otherwise do comment and ask further doubts if required. I have edited your post with MathJax, so you will know what to do next time, by visiting this post and seeing what I did.

Comment: Thank you @TeresaLisbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of a triangle formed by two adjacent vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is given by $\frac{1}{2} |\vec A \times \vec B|= \frac{1}{2} |\vec A| |\vec B| \sin \theta$. If you find area by LHS in above $\sin \theta $ as taken care of. Other thing is the cros product is represented by the determinant which gives you a vector, them find its modulus.

Comment: Yes , so how is the ABsin theta = discriminant formula is my Q?

Comment: Why does the discriminant formula gives the coordinates for the magnitude of A x B ?.

Comment: It is not "discriminant" it is determinant. This is the elementary information of  cross product. for a triangle $\vec A|$ is the base and $|\vec B| \sin \theta $ is the height of the triangle. If you remove $1/2$ you get the area of ||gram. see   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product